# How to select a row from MySQL when there are no rows in another table

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to select data from one table ONLY IF there is no data within the other table for the user and site.

This is what I have so far.

```
SELECT 
    l.link_id,
    l.link_name,
    l.link_points,
    l.link_time,
    COUNT(uc.user_id) AS clicks
FROM 
    links AS l LEFT OUTER JOIN
    (SELECT user_id, site_id FROM user_clicks WHERE site_id = l.link_id AND user_id = ".$user['user_id'].") as uc
    USING (link_id)
GROUP BY
    l.link_id
```

Which is my current attempt at it but I get "Unknown column 'l.link_id' in 'where clause'" when trying to pull that data in the outer join.

How do I go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This here should work:

```
SELECT 
    l.link_id,
    l.link_name,
    l.link_points,
    l.link_time,
    COUNT(uc.user_id) AS clicks
FROM 
    links AS l LEFT JOIN
    user_clicks uc ON uc.site_id = l.link_id 
WHERE user_id = ".$user['user_id']."
    AND uc.site_id IS NULL
GROUP BY
    l.link_id
```

The LEFT JOIN selects everything from table `links` and with the `uc.site_id IS NULL` in the `WHERE` clause you make sure, that there is no row in the other table. Actually it's not important which column you name there, as long as it's from `user_clicks`

Comment: This solution doesn't produce any errors but also doesn't return anything when it the links database doesn't have an entry for the user and the site.

Comment: @DavidMacaulay That's what you were asking for? No? Then please explain again, what you want to achieve.